# 2013 National Bike Challenge

Tags: discussion

The 2013 National Bike Challenge (http://nationalbikechallenge.org) is starting up. I just learned about it today, but it seems like a great cause. It's sponsored by the League of American Bicyclists and Kimberly-Clark (as part of an effort to get employees to commute by bike). And selfishly, I'm happy to be safer as more people decide to ride.

This seems like a great event to help promote on Bicycles.SE. I suggest that this might be a good thing to link to, maybe through a Community Promotion Ad or something. Here's a link for the Guide for Advocacy Organizations:

http://www.endomondo.com/campaign/national/aoguide

We could alse consider creating a Bicycles.SE team.

Comment: By the way, I just realized that there's a post dedicated to Community Promotion Ads, so I added an answer there: http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/819/3649

Comment: I love this idea! Count me in.

Answer (score 4):

I just created a Bicycles Stack Exchange team:

http://www.endomondo.com/teams/9613287

Please let me know if there are any branding problems with me having created this. I'm also more than happy to add moderators as owners of the team if that would be more appropriate than me owning it myself. I really don't want to cause any trouble, so if there's a better way to make this officially sanctioned, I would be happy to change things or delete it.

EDIT: As requested by @Aarthi, I'm deleting the team pending discussion among the community. Presumably if this answer gets enough upvotes, then we can create the team and make it official.

EDIT: I recreated the team at @freiheit's request. The new one is clearly unofficial, but hopefully with some upvotes, we can get some official recognition.

Comment: @freiheit At present, I named it "Bicycles Stack Exchange", but I can rename it to "Stack Exchange" if you like it better.

Comment: I've joined the team :)

Comment: Just to clarify: I needed you to delete the *logo* -- this can't be the "official" team because it isn't sponsored by Stack Exchange. If you all want to have a Unofficial Bicycles Stack Exchange NBC team, by all means do so! :)

Comment: @Aarthi I'll do that for now, but long term, I think it's much better to have something official that can potentially bring new people to the Bicycles.SE community. It's too bad that the Stack Exchange hasn't given the trademarks over to a non-profit foundation, which would let the community represent itself.

Comment: @amcnabb There's been precedents of other sites' communities self-organizing for good causes. (Gaming.SE immediately comes to mind.) You do not need our sponsorship to do something fun with the other users here, and the lack of an official blessing shouldn't *stop* you from building a better community and attracting new users. We love seeing our users do stuff like this! The official-ness of it is really rather secondary.

Comment: @AnnaLear These types of issues highlight the inherent wall between the community and the platform. Foundations (as are common for open source projects) ensure that a community remains independent and stable into the future.